# VS Code uses high CPU even if it is closed

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, cpu, activity-monitor, visual-studio-code

VS Code takes 100% CPU usage even it is not open. I ran the `ps aux | grep PID` command to check the details but can't understand anything. Here's the output:

```
tawhid           27099 100.0  0.1 447352160  11856   ??  R     7:18PM 151:14.95 /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Renderer).app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper (Renderer) --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/bootstrap-fork --type=fileWatcher
tawhid           31889   0.0  0.0 408628368   1616 s000  S+   10:28PM   0:00.00 grep 27099
```

Can anyone explain what process or extension uses so high CPU percentage?
I have MacBook Air 2020. I have installed a lot of extensions out of curiosity.

Comment: It would seem you have an extension to VS Code that that is hanging as a separate process. See this thread: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/101555